# Passing array of latLng points to server via ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a polyline which I would like to pass to the server via an ajax POST request.  I have an array of LatLng points and a string for the polyline name, both of which I am trying to send to the server.

However, when I try to send the array of points I get an error.  Sending just the name (string) leaves me with no error, so I believe the problem is that I am trying to send a MVC Array in the data, though I am not positive if that is an issue.  The code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '/saveRoute',
    data: {
      routeCoords: points,
      routeName: name
    },
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
```

Now the points array is just a regular javascript array, and each time a user adds a point to the map, I push the new LatLng object onto the array.  Is there anyway to get the array of LatLng points to successfully pass to the server?

The error I see in the console is listed below:
    TypeError: this is undefined

in the script %7Bmain,geometry%7d.js

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: My initial idea for a solution was to go through each point in the array, stringify it, and push it onto a new array of strings.  Then when I want to reload the route to the map I could parse the array of strings and construct new points.  I just feel like this solution is a bit hacky and it seems like there should be an easier solution that avoids conversion of points to strings..

Comment: Ummm, if handled properly, there shouldn't be need for that much conversion of points to strings I believe. Am a bit unclear on contents of your array, does it contain google.maps.LatLng objects? or does it contain coordinate sets like: myArray = [[32.196,-98.777], [32.78, 98.111]]; if like the latter, then a simple JSON.stringify on the whole array at once should be fine. Also, I can't remember for sure as I have rarely used it, whether $.ajax encodes data values or not, might need to encodeURIComponent(points)

Comment: So, if your 'points' arry is all google.maps.LatLng objects, loop through them and push array containing lat & lng of each into myArray: myArray.push([points[i].lat(), points[i].lng()]); When you use JSON.stringify on the entire array later then, data type will be preserved if you handle json properly on the server and when re-reading the json imported back onto client-side at later date.

Comment: @astupidname So 'points' contains all LatLng objects.  So yeah, I think I will have to push the lat/lng values into a new array. I wasn't sure if there was some simple error I was making, but thanks for the suggestion I think it will work fine as the size of the points array should definitely < 100 so I doubt it'll make a huge amount of time.